# Is it possible to 'break' or 'return' mid-page in an html document?

Tags: html, asp-classic

I was wondering if there was a way to stop a page from parsing the rest of the document. I attempted to add:

```
if Request("mode") <> "admin" then
  response.write "</body>"
  response.write "</html>"
end if
```

but (as I'm sure you're aware) that does nothing.

There's many alternatives I could use, but I was wondering if there was a quick'n'dirty trick I could throw in temporarily?

Thanks

*[edit]
Clarification:

The rest of the page is fairly standard html with a few code snippets. I was just using asp to add the tags halfway up the page under certain circumstances. So basically, if you're in 'admin' mode, you get the full page, but otherwise it cuts off halfway down.
And yes, I realise this is technically very unwise, I was just wondering out of interest if html (or various scripting languages) had a method for doing this.*

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: You should mention what technology that is, it's certainly not just HTML. ASP perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

response.end

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Add a response.end() in there too and the remainder of the text will not be sent to the client. Two questions still:

- is this classic asp?
- this is a very bad idea, are you aware of that?